# JHIPSTER. Add optional relationship on CSV fake data

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

Hi have the following entity on Jhipser 6

```
entity Proveedor {
  nombre String required unique,
  descripcion String required
}
```

And recently I have added a new relationship

```
relationship OneToOne {
  Proveedor{user(login)} to User
}
```

Everything works as expected. But when I try to insert null values...

```
id;nombre;descripcion;user_id
1;Proveedor 1;Proveedor 1;5
2;Proveedor 2;Proveedor 2;NULL
```

But I get:

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20210304164226_added_entity_Proveedor.xml::20210304164226-1-data::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: 
     Data conversion error converting "'' (PROVEEDOR: ""USER_ID"" BIGINT)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.proveedor(id, nombre, descripcion, user_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) [22018-200]
```

I have fixed it manual adding user_id column on the liquibase file that raised the error: 20210304164226_added_entity_Proveedor.xml, on loadData the column user_id was missing.

```xml
    <changeSet id="20210304164226-1-data" author="jhipster" context="faker">
        <loadData
                  file="config/liquibase/fake-data/proveedor.csv"
                  separator=";"
                  tableName="proveedor">
            <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
            <column name="nombre" type="string"/>
            <column name="descripcion" type="string"/>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-loadcolumn - JHipster (and/or extensions) can add load columns here -->
            <column name="user_id" type="numeric"/>
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>
```

I'm not sure if is a jHipster issue or I have done something wrong.
It's the correct way or I have done something incorrect on the .jdl or .csv?

Answer (score 0):

Your csv looks correct based on the [Liquibase documentation about loadData](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/load-data.html).